# How to access dynamic key values of a JSON object in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I'm facing issues in retrieving the JSON data.

Here am getting the JSON with dynamic keys. And I need to access that dynamic key's values. The dynamic key is coming from URL and am fetching that key's data from DB.

Here is my sample data.

```
let roleData = [
  {
    "assetCategory": {
       "canCreate": false,
       "canView": false,
       "canUpdate": false,
       "canDelete": false,
       "isMenu": false,
       "parent": "settings"
     }
  }
]
```

In the above JSON, I've got `assetCategory` object. But this value is completely dynamic. I might get other values too in the place of `assetCategory`. So without knowing this key, it's getting difficult for me to access the data.

Is there any way to access this dynamic object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
let data = [
  {
    "assetCategory": {
       "canCreate": false,
       "canView": false,
       "canUpdate": false,
       "canDelete": false,
       "isMenu": false,
       "parent": "settings"
     }
  }
]


let unknownNames = data.map( item => Object.keys(item)) // returns ['assetCategory']
//Returns array of all the unknown names
console.log(unknownNames);
```

Comment: Thanks. But when I use the above solution, am getting this as the result in console  ```[ [ '$__', 'isNew', 'errors', '_doc', '$locals', '$op', '$init' ] ]```

Comment: This seems to work.
https://repl.it/repls/IcyBubblyStructures
Maybe try using a different variable name besides 'data'

Comment: It's working in onine editors. But not in my code. Still getting, ```$__```

Comment: This is what am giving as the input to the code you have commented

Comment: ```[ { assetCategory:
     { canCreate: false,
       canView: false,
       canUpdate: false,
       canDelete: false,
       isMenu: false,
       parent: 'settings' } } ]```

Comment: Could you post the code snippet you're using. Problem seems to be something else.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Your answer was helpful. I learnt a new method to get the data. But sorry, I got the answer by my own. It's my mistake that I didn't mention that am getting the key value from payload.

Answer (score 4):

You should use `Object.keys(...)` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

For example:

```js
const a = [
  {
    "assetCategory": {
       "canCreate": false,
       "canView": false,
       "canUpdate": false,
       "canDelete": false,
       "isMenu": false,
       "parent": "settings"
     }
  }
];

const name = Object.keys(a[0])[0]; // --> "assetCategory"
console.log(a[0][name]) // --> {"canCreate": false, ...}
```

Comment: When I use your answer, am getting this, ```$__```. What does this mean?

Answer (score 1):

you can get all keys by `Object.keys(data[0].assetCategory)`. and then `data[0].assetCategory[varWithKeyValue]` or if it's dynamic `data[0].assetCategory['can' + 'Create']`

Comment: No, I want to get ```assetCategory``` object itself. But the problem is, ```assetCategory``` is a dynamic key. In that place I might get ```assetStatus``` and I should get ```assetStatus``` 's object too

Comment: then you can do the same with `Object.keys(data[0])`.

Comment: in case if you want to get only keys of the object the modern way is `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(data[0])`.